# Subtract Micrometer/Prometheus different metrics for the same labels one from another

Tags: prometheus, grafana, micrometer, victoriametrics

I have 2 Micrometer

```
# HELP jms_payment_queue_in_total Current size of messages in JMS queue
# TYPE jms_payment_queue_in_total counter
jms_payment_queue_in_total{service_id="1056",} 2.0
jms_payment_queue_in_total{service_id="1050",} 4.0
jms_payment_queue_in_total{service_id="792",} 1.0
jms_payment_queue_in_total{service_id="584",} 1.0
```

and

```
# HELP jms_payment_queue_out_total Current size of messages in JMS queue
# TYPE jms_payment_queue_out_total counter
jms_payment_queue_out_total{success="success",service_id="1050",} 5.0
jms_payment_queue_out_total{success="success",service_id="977",} 22.0
jms_payment_queue_out_total{success="success",service_id="955",} 8.0
```

I like to plot a prometheus query to build `jms_payment_queue_in_total{service_id="584",} - jms_payment_queue_out_total{success="success",service_id="584",}`  (for all possible same success and service_id fields). How to do that?

I tired to plot

```
abs_payment_total{service_id="1050"} - ignoring(success) jms_payment_queue_out_total{service_id="1050"}
```

in Grafana, where I definitely have points for both values, but it plots nothing. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add missing [filter](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#filtering) on `success`:

```
abs_payment_total{service_id="1050",success=""} - ignoring(success)
abs_payment_total{service_id="1050",success="success"}
```

This query adds `success=""` filter to the left-hand side of `-` operator in order to filter out [time series](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#time-series) with non-empty `success` label.

The query adds `success="success"` filter to the right-hand side of `-` in order to select only time series with that label.

The query uses `ignoring(success)` in order to ignore `success` label when finding pairs of time series with identical labels on the left and the right side of `-` according to [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching).

P.S. you can use the following query in order to calculate the needed difference across all the `service_id` labels:

```
abs_payment_total{success=""} - ignoring(success) abs_payment_total{success="success"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use promQL aggregation operators `max(select maximum over dimensions)`

```
max(jms_payment_queue_in_total{service_id="584"}) by (service_id)
- max(jms_payment_queue_out_total{success="success",service_id="584"}) by (service_id)
```

or

```
max(max_over_time(jms_payment_queue_in_total{service_id="584"})[1s]) by (service_id)
- max(max_over_time(jms_payment_queue_out_total{success="success",service_id="584"})[1s]) by (service_id)
```

Comment: unfortunately, `bad_data: invalid parameter "query": 1:68: parse error: unexpected <by>`

Comment: I edit my answer, you can use aggregation operators max() by